# Break process in case of fail

Tags: elixir

I'm developing a API in elixir and I have a processo executing 6 actions in a row. My question is how can I interrupt this execution in case of fail in any of this 6 actions?

I'd not like to cascade into multiple case blocks.

Actually I'd like something like "return".

Does anyone have a good solution for this?

Comment: Can you show this code, or a representative equivalent thereof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a series of consecutive conditionals in Elixir (e.g. multiple case blocks), the `with` clause (statement? operator?) can be useful.

There is an example in the [Elixir docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#with/1).

Compare a smelly mess of nested case statements like this:

```
case op1(x) do
  {:ok, result1} -> 
     case op2(result1) do
        {:ok, result2} -> 
            case op3(result2) do
               {:ok, result3} -> {:ok, result3}
               {:error, error} -> {:error, error}      
            end
        {:error, error} -> {:error, error}      
     end   
  {:error, error} -> {:error, error}      
end
```

That's *really* hard to follow and the `{:error, error} -> {:error, error}` bits feel redundant.  Basically, we just want to keep drilling into sequential operations (1, 2, 3, ...) or exit with an error.

We can rewrite the above using the `with` syntax -- pay close attention to the direction of the arrows!

```
with {:ok, result1} <- op1(x),
     {:ok, result2} <- op2(result1) do
  op3(result3)
else
  {:error, error} -> {:error, error}
end
```

or more tersely, omit the `else` block if no special error handling is required:

```
with {:ok, result1} <- op1(x),
     {:ok, result2} <- op2(result1) do
  op3(result3)
end
```

You use a comma to separate one operation after another, finally culminating in a `do` block where you can perform the final operation.

If any of the operations fail, execution can be routed to match down in an optional `else` block -- this is most useful if you need to distinguish between different return values (e.g. if specific logging is desired), otherwise the `else` block is redundant and can often be omitted.

Understanding the `with` block is a big step in writing cleaner Elixir code.  An alternative to using the `with` syntax can be writing multiple function signatures to handle the output of each step, but that feel like a lot of busy-work that's not always justified.

Comment: `else` block in the form `{:error, error} -> {:error, error}` is completely redundant. `{:error, error}` will be returned from `with/1` without it, once encountered.

Comment: You're right, of course -- I have updated the explanation.  I find it's helpful to have the `else` block there as an example, however, in the case that you do need to match on different return values.

Answer (score 0):

Not having a return option really messed with my mind for a while in elixir.  I recommend you embrace pattern matching.  I know this seems incorrect but you'll eventually realize the simplicity behind it.  You can do it without nesting, just make a new function for each pattern you expect.

Here's a snippet where I basically recurse on `self()`

```
  ...

  def handle_cast({:get_name, port, container}, state) do
    app_name = Map.get(container, "Labels") |> Map.get("app")
    GenServer.cast(self(), {:domain_map, app_name, port, container})
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  def handle_cast({:containers, containers}, state) do
    Enum.map(containers, fn container ->
      GenServer.cast(self(), {:container, container})
    end)

    {:noreply, state}
  end

  def handle_cast({:container, container}, state) do
    Enum.map(Map.get(container, "Ports"), fn port ->
      GenServer.cast(self(), {:get_name, port, container})
    end)

    {:noreply, state}
  end

 ...
```

If the pattern isn't matched, that's basically your return statement.